# How to print a reverse linked list without using recursion in Java?

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list, iteration, singly-linked-list

I try printing a reverse linked list without recursion and reversing the linked list. How can I do that?

**Questions**: How to print a reverse linked list without using recursion and not reversing the list?

**Requirements**: No extra space, cannot reverse a linked list, cannot use recursion.

Here is the definition of the linked list Node

```
class Node {
  int value;
  Node next;

  public Node(int val) {
    this.value = val;
  }
}
```

Here is my recursion version of printReverseLinkedList:

```
public void printReverseList(Node head) {
    Node temp = head;
    if (temp.next != null) {
        printReverseList(temp.next);
    }
    System.out.print(temp.value);
}
```

**Performace does not matter, because I just want to do in this way.**

Comment: Build a reversed string?

Comment: No, that is not the correct way. @JornVernee

Comment: i think it should be temp != null, that is a long as the head is not empty While(temp != null)

Comment: Alright, please ignore this detail @SeekAddo

Comment: Does the performance matter? You can do this in `O(n^2)`, first pointer is an index of current iteration, the second pointer is to remember the index element printed in previous iteration.

Comment: no such thing as a pointer in java

Comment: It does not matter, if you can provide the code, I will deeply appreciated. @JaroslawPawlak

Comment: what? @scarecrow---------

Comment: Each node needs to have a reference to the node that came before it, or the task will be impossible. This is known as a [doubly linked list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list)

Comment: Can you use another data-structure such as `Stack<Node>` ?

Comment: Yes, please provide the code @Arefe

Comment: Are you allowed to change the elements (destroy the list?). Then you can just find the tail, print it, delete it, repeat until the list is empty. Otherwise I agree with Pawlak's answer to just track the last printed entry and iterate over that.

Comment: No. @user1676075......

Comment: @JohannesH's answer is exactly what I had in mind.

Comment: @Michael Not true, see my / JaroslawPawlak's answer

Comment: @user1676075 if you remember the last one or delete it has the same efficiency - it's both `O(n^2)`. Only thing you save when deleting the last element is the second pointer.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak It's the only way, really. SO no surprise we came up with the same solution ;) Mind looking voer my code to see if I amde any booboo? can't test it right now

Comment: Can you use implicit recursion rather than explicit?

Comment: @JohannesH. I am a bit busy right now as well. I wrote it in pseudocode and then noticed your solution so I just deleted my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you may neither reverse the list, nor use recursion, the only way to do this is this:

```
public void printReversList(Node head) {

    Node current = head; // used to search through the list
    Node last    = null; // stores the last element that we printed

    while (last != head) { // = we didn't print everything yet

        // find next element to print - it's one element before we reach "last"
        while (current.next != last) {
            current = current.next;
        }

        // Store the current element as the new last and print it
        last  = current;
        system.out.print(last.value);

        // reset current and start all over
        current = head;
    }
}
```

It is highly ineffective, but there is no other way I can think of.

Comment: I copy your code into eclipse and change Node last = current to last = current and I got a nullpointerexception in system.out.print(last.value)? @Johannes H.

Comment: Can you put a condition and try again `if (head == null) return; `. put beginning of the method definition. `Node last = current to last = current` should be the right way to compose the code.

Comment: @SHE Eclipse is correct. That was a copy & paste mistake on my part - I fixed it. However I don't quite get the `NullPointerException` - I couldn't test my code, but it should not ever reach a state where `last == null`, unless `head == null`

Answer (score 3):

How about using a Stack and then poping ? You said using another data-structure will be fine. This is not the fine code, but, should get the job done.

```
public void printReversList(Node head) {

    Stack<Node> stack = new Stack<>();

    while (head != null){

       stack.push(head);
       head = head.next;          
   }

   while (!stack.isEmpty()){
       System.out.println(stack.pop());
   }
}
```

Comment: stack extra space? @Arefe

Comment: Okay, sorry then, but, I asked you earlier.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
public void printReverseList(Node head) {
            if(head == null) return;
            Node prev = null;
            Node revers = head;
            Node nex = null;

            while (revers != null){
                nex = revers.next;
                revers.next = prev;

                prev = revers;
                revers = nex;

            }
            System.out.println(prev);
        }
```

Comment: I need to print, not reverse. @Seek Addo

Comment: yes and you can call the reverse in the node and after that print it. @SHE

Comment: I don't think changing the definition of `Node` is allowed

Comment: It seems too complicated @SeekAddo

Comment: The definition of the node is different @SeekAddo

Comment: I tried your code and change pre to pre.value in the end and it just print a wrong result @SeekAddo

Comment: @SHE i think you dont need the value. it should work

Comment: It's also basically turning the list into a dobuly linked list, which is kinda cheating.

Comment: @SeekAddo The `.value` in the print instruction is definately needed. `Node` does not override `.toString()`, so `Object.toString()` is used and it will not print the value but a hash code of the `Node`

Comment: @JohannesH. i normally implement the toString method in my first code that i showed and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @SeekAddo Well, changing the definition of Node is not allowed (that eans no `toString()` either). Plus, your answer as-is is still not working

Answer (score 0):

```
void ReversePrint(Node head) {
    // This is a "method-only" submission.
    // You only need to complete this method. 
    Stack<Node> stk=new Stack<>();

    Node temp=head;
    while(temp!=null){
        stk.push(temp);
        temp=temp.next;
    }
    while(!stk.isEmpty()){
        System.out.println(stk.pop().data);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void printReverseList(Node head) {
        Node node = head;
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            if (head == null){
                System.out.println(head.data); 
            }
            else{
               while (node != null){
                list.add(0, node.data);
                node = node.next;
            }
            for (int item:list){
                System.out.println(item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please provide some accompanying explanation